# JBoss EAP: vault in domain mode

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I have a JBoss  EAP 7.0 in domain mode. I have a domain controller with several managed hosts.

Considering that, I am trying to use "vault passwords".

What I am currently doing (via Shell scripts):

- create keystore + vault
- put passwords in the vault
- add the vault to the host configuration (via
  /host=/core-service=vault:add)
- add the vault to the host master configuration (via
  /host=master/core-service=vault:add)

**=> In the doc I didn't find any mention to that. Do we need to have vault conf in both hosts (domain controller and managed host) ?**

- push passwords to server groups, profiles, etc. (datasouces...) try
  to start server-group

**=> I have a failure :**

```
    /server-group=<MYSERVERGROUP>:start-servers
   {
        "outcome" => "failed",
        "failure-description" => {"host-failure-descriptions" => {"<MYHOST>" => "WFLYCTL0158: java.lang.SecurityException: WFLYSRV0228: security exception"}},
        "rolled-back" => true,
        "result" => {}
    }
```

- I try to reload the configuration of my hosts as follow:

```
/host=<MYHOST>:reload(use-current-host-config=true)

/host=master:reload(use-current-host-config=true, use-current-domain-config=true)
```

- after a while, my host  disepear in my domain controller
  (maybe because of the reload operation...) then nothing can work

**=> Do I need to reload my hosts to avoid "security exception"? If no, what can I do?**

Comment: - Appears to be a known bug in EAP 7.1, and yet to be fixed. In order to get it working, a restart is needed after adding the secret value in the vault keystore such that the JBoss server configuration would know that this is a valid vault string that is going to be added using the CLI command.

[https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6573]

Comment: @Giri thanks but when I restart my domain controller, it doesn't know my host anymore... all the configuration is left. I really don't know why.